# Get certain celery tasks to only run during certain hours

Tags: python, django, celery

Using Celery, with (if it matters) a rabbitmq broker and django as the result backend.

I have many thousands of tasks, such that it will take weeks to complete them all. However, some of them I only want to be run between certain hours of the day. This is because they involve downloading files from a public server that has explicitly requested this behaviour. Each task takes several minutes to complete. How best to go about this?

Comment: What about just checking for the time in the celery task, and then just trying later: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#using-a-custom-retry-delay

Comment: Rachel - My worry there would be inefficiency. We might be repeatedly retrying the same tasks at the wrong time of day, if for example Celery blows through 100,000 tasks and reschedules them for later on. When later on comes, there is not enough time to finish all 100,000 so most of them have to get rescheduled again. And again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Crontab schedules](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#crontab-schedules) to setup what you need.

Comment: I'm not sure how to make this work. Ahead of time I don't know when precisely to schedule each task for, just that it should only occur sometime between 18:00 PM and 09:00 AM. That might be tomorrow or next week, as long as I get to it some time and it only occurs within the designated hours.

Comment: In documentation you have whole list of examples how you can configure crontab. In your case you could do something like this: `crontab(minute='*/10', hour='18-9')` which will trigger your task every 10 minutes between 18PM and 9AM.